# Running OpenCV code in ROS- error: ‘DescriptorMatcher’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

I have installed the OpenCV on my machine along with the `opencv_bridge`. I am trying to use this script in my ROS package:

https://github.com/spillai/recognition-utils/blob/master/FLAIR/flair.hpp

The problem is that when I include it in my file (like this):

```
#include "opencv2/core/version.hpp"
#include "flair.hpp"
```

I am getting this error:

```
/home/osboxes/catkin_ws/src/cipek/src/flair.hpp:71:11: error: ‘DescriptorMatcher’ was not declared in this scope
   cv::Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> _matcher;
```

There are many more errors which follow this one, but I don't want to put it all here, because it is long, unless someone needs it. I haven't modified the file from the GitHub repository. How can I fix this issue?

EDIT

After adding:

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
```

To `flair.hpp` file, I am getting this error:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/opencv2/core.hpp:52:0,
             from /home/osboxes/catkin_ws/src/cipek/src/flair.hpp:23,
             from /home/osboxes/catkin_ws/src/cipek/src/ardrone_test_CPP.cpp:8:
/usr/local/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:234:15: error: redefinition of ‘union Cv32suf’
 typedef union Cv32suf
```

Comment: which of those includes creates the problem? `opencv` or `flair`

Comment: `DescriptionMatcher` is in `features2d.hpp` Try to inlcude: `#include "opencv2/core.hpp"` and `#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"`

Comment: @TarickWelling flair

Comment: @DimChtz check out my edited question

Comment: @GrzegorzBrzęczyszczykiewicz Yeah, just noticed that flair includes: `opencv2/opencv.hpp`. Which means you only need to include flair and select features2d module during building. Alternatively, you could remove the include line from flair.hpp and then include manually: `opencv2/core.hpp`, `opencv2/highgui.hpp`, `opencv2/features2d.hpp` and finally `flair.hpp` .

Comment: @DimChtz I've changed it so now flair.hpp doesn't include anything, and my file includes: #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "flair.hpp" but I got so many errors that they do not even fit in the console.